Visual Studio[2022] is continuously prompting for login credentials when I try to restore the NuGet packages or build the solution
Visual studio[2022 enterprise] is popping up the log in credentials continuously when I try to restore the NuGet package or build the solution.
Because of this I couldn't able to run my solution or update the packages.
I have tried clearing NuGet cache, uninstalled and re installed Visual studio, repair Visual studio. However, none of these actions have resolved the issue.
I have attached a screenshot of the login prompt for reference. Any assistance in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

I have also attached the error message I am getting and also some warning messages.


Looks like the source is your private package source hosted on Azure DevOps, please add nuget.org source to see if you can restore packages.


Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/microsoft/_packaging/WDG/nuget/v3/index.json.

Looks like the source is your private package source hosted on Azure DevOps.
Please check the following points:

Please make sure the account you login to is a member in your DevOps and  has sufficient permission in DevOps.
Please make sure it's a valid source URL. You can check this in your feeds via this guide.

You can also expand the NuGet Package Manager section and add a nuget.org(if you don't have one) source in Package Sources and switch WDG to nugt.org to restore your packages and check if you can restore packages from public nuget org.

https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Check all Package Sources in your nuget.config file.(Windows:%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config)
 <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="devops" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxx/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>

